# Java - Why static is important in this case

Tags: java, generics, static

I've two questions that relates to the following code (Linked Bag):

```
public class LinkedBag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

private Node first;    // beginning of bag
private int N;         // number of elements in bag

private class Node {
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
}
```

and this one

```
public class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private Node<Item> first;    // beginning of bag
private int N;               // number of elements in bag

// helper linked list class
private static class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> next;
}
```

1. What's the difference between `Node<Item>` and Node here? both implementations are generic, so how Node and  `Node<Item>`differ here ?
2. What's the meaning of static in the second version, why is it crucial ? ( doesn't compile without static).

Thanks !

Comment: I'm pretty sure that just means, the one that is static, Is that it is the same throughout all instances you create of that class

Comment: `What's the difference between Node and Node here? both implementations are generic` ,don't know what you're refering to, first definition is not generic.could you clarify what you mean by the first point

Comment: @Ramanlfc, yeah, I noticed and fixed that.

Comment: Lots of great answers, thanks guys !!

Comment: Definitely an upvote to all of your  answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a nested class is *not* static (called an *inner class*), it means that every instance belongs to an instance of the enclosing class. Therefore in the first example, a `Node` instance belongs to a `LinkedBag<Item>`, so it already has a generic type `Item` (from `LinkedBag<Item>`).

An instance of a static nested class does *not* belong to an instance of the enclosing type, so it does not get the generic type parameter from an enclosing instance - you need to give it its own generic parameter.

Looking at the source code for the various `Collection` and `Map` implementations in the standard Java collections framework, you can see that both approaches to `Node` classes (static and non-static) are commonly used.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!

Comment: @Niminim No problem. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

If your nested class is not `static`, then it's an inner class, and the enclosing class's type parameter `Item` is in scope.  However, if your nested class is `static`, then the enclosing class's type parameter is *not* in scope, because that type parameter has to do with an instance of the enclosing class, which is not relevant for a `static` nested class.

Here, the `static` class `Node` declares its own `Item` type parameter.  It could have declared any other name and it would have been equivalent.  You should not receive a compiler error using `Node<Item>` in your second case (with the `static` class); that is legal.

Comment: Great answer! thanks! good to know that I could have used any other name with Node and it would have been equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. What's the difference between `Node<Item>` and `Node` here?

Adding a generic parameter is necessary because Java prohibits `static` inner classes of generic types from referencing type parameters of their outer types.

> 2. What's the meaning of `static` in the second version?

`static` means that `Node` instances do not get a reference to their parent class, and can be created outside of its context if it is necessary. It is not exactly "crucial", but shrinks your node by a third (two references vs. three references), which is an advantage.

Comment: Really great answer! Now I understand the advantage of using static in this case. without static it doesn't compile, that's why it was crucial here.